# Is there any humor or meaning to the conversation about Yuri's dream and how many Hinatas there were?

Tags: angel-beats

In episode 5, Otonashi and Angel had a conversation about Yuri's dream and how many Hinatas there were, which seemed totally random and out of nowhere. When I first watched that episode, I didn't get the humor and meaning that I suspected were there in the conversation. Are those remarks just some disposable lines, or are they foreshadowing or references to something?

---

#### The curious conversation between Otonashi and Angel

> **音無**：「すまん！ゆりの調子が不安定だ。 原因は、昨夜夢に日向が出てきて……」
>
> **日向**：『今日の俺と明日の俺が同じ俺だと思うな。気を付けな。』
>
> **音無**：「……と忠告してきたことによる。そして今、その忠告が事実であることをゆりが証明しちまったところなんだ。」
>
> **天使**：「日向君は二人いるの？」
>
> **音無**：「あ、ああ、そういうことになる。」
>
> **天使**：「三人以上いるかもしれない？」
>
> **音無**：「え？ああ、ありえる。」
>
> **天使**：「お気の毒に。」
>
> ---
>
> **Otonashi**: Sorry! Yuri's a little emotionally unstable. Because last night, Hinata showed up in her dream and—
>
> **Hinata**: Don't think that the me from today and tomorrow will be the same. Watch out.
>
> **Otonashi**: That's what he said, and Yuri just proved it.
>
> **Angel**: Are there two Hinata-kun's?
>
> **Otonashi**: Y-Yeah... that's right.
>
> **Angel**: Is there a chance that there's more than three of him?
>
> **Otonashi**: Huh? Oh, uh... it's possible.
>
> **Angel**: I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: Anywhere we can see the original Japanese? Sometimes the joke is not understandable if you translate it into English.

Comment: If there are two Hinatas, of yesterday and of tomorrow, then there surely is a third one, of today.

Comment: Nether your question nor your answer makes much sense. What problem is you question referring to? How does your answer address this problem? None of this is clear to me. Your question and answer just seems to be a continuation of one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversation actually foreshadows a future event where Angel makes an aggressive clone of herself using Guard Skills: Harmonics.

> Are there two Hinata-kun's? Is there a chance that there's more than three of him?

In episode 8, Hinata reciprocated this saying to Angel, which is in itself a gag.

[image: Hinata was saying what Angel had said about him]

> Don't think that the me from today and tomorrow will be the same. Watch out.

This is what the SSS members were worrying about in episode 9: which "Angel" would wake up from the coma after Kanade had absorbed all her clones?

[image: Shiina talked!?]

> I'm sorry to hear that. (お気の毒に)

The second kanji character used in Angel's expression of pity, 毒 ("poison"), was actually shown right at Hinata's face in episode 2, the last time he was made to be sacrificed by Yurippe. In episode 5, he had to make his sacrifices again at the coercion of Yurippe, but don't worry, the maxim "people die if they are killed" doesn't apply in the Afterlife World.

[image: O Ki no Doku ni]

Answer (score 4):

The joke here, I think, is that before this conversation, Hinata showed up in front of Yuri and behaved very differently from yesterday (before Yuri dreamed about him), so Otonashi said that the warning came true: Hinata really changed. Since Hinata said, "don't think that the me from today and tomorrow will be the same", tomorrow, he might change again, making Kanade say that there could be more than three of him.

Comment: Okay...so it is just a kind of silly conversation? I thought there are references or inside jokes made.

Comment: Yep. That's about it, based on the Japanese text you posted.

Answer (score 3):

> Angel: Is there a chance that there's more than three of him?
>
> Otonashi: Huh? Oh, uh... it's possible.
>
> Angel: I'm sorry to hear that.

The humour here is that Angel's basically saying *having one Hinata is bad enough* and she is sad to hear there is more of him.

> Hinata: Don't think that the me from today and tomorrow will be the same. Watch out.
>
> Angel: Are there two Hinata-kun's?

There's a misunderstanding here where Hinata is saying that how is personality is one day is different to how it is another day. Angel has mistaken this as being two distinctly different Hinatas .